# Formatting strings in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net, html, string, razor

I am currently writing a small templating system in ASP.NET to allow users to add content. For example, the user can enter the string (variable type is string).

```
topHeader[x] = "They think it's all over. It is now!";
```

However, one change that's needed is the ability to add some basic HTML tags within this content, so the following can be done

```
topHeader[x] = "They think it's all over. <strong>It is now!</strong>";
```

or

```
topHeader[x] = "They think it's all over. <a title="Football News" href="URL">It is now!</a>";
```

If you add such things into strings now they are not formatted as HTML, but I want to somehow escape them so that they can be. Naturally I've looked on the Internet for the answer, but as Razor is fairly new there's not much out there to help me out.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) implementation holding your HTML source.

<strike>Razor plans to have a helper method to do this for you, but, AFAIK, it doesn't yet, so I believe you'll need to create your own class that implements the interface and returns your HTML from the `GetHtmlString()` method.</strike>
**EDIT**: You can use the `HtmlString` class.

You can either change your `topHeader` dictionary to hold `IHtmlString`s instead of `String`s, or you can leave your code as is, but wrap it in an `HtmlString` in the Razor view:

```
<tag>@new HtmlString(topHeader[x])</tag>
```

Make sure to correctly escape any non-HTML special characters.

Answer (score 9):

The helper method they added is called **Html.Raw() and it is much cleaner**.

Here is an example:

```
@Html.Raw("Hello <a>World</a>!")
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! And it's easier than the other answers provided.

Answer (score 4):

SLaks is right, but you don't need to write your own implementation of `IHtmlString`, there's one built in to `System.Web` called `HtmlString`. So:

```
topHeader[x] = new HtmlString("They think it's all over. <a title=\"Football News\" href=\"URL\">It is now!</a>");
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried this, but receive "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HtmlString' to 'string'" Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @EnderMB: Change the dictionary to contain `IHtmlString` or `object`.